Reasonable Parameter Ranges for Bates Model
Bates dynamic is as follows:
$$
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} = (r - \delta) \, dt + \sqrt{V_t} \, dW_{1t} + dN_t
$$
$$
dV_t = \kappa (\theta - V_t) \, dt + \sigma \sqrt{V_t} \, dW_{2t}
$$
with $dW_{1t} dW_{2t} = \rho \, dt$ and $N_t$ is a compound Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and independent jumps $J$ such that:
$$
\ln(1 + J) \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \ln(1 + \beta) - \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2, \alpha^2 \right)
$$
The model requires the following eight parameters:
$$
\delta, \theta, \kappa, \rho, \alpha, \beta, \lambda, v_0
$$
What would be a reasonable range for each of these parameters? I need this information because I am generating a large number of volatility surfaces, and I want to ensure that the set of parameters used is realistic.

"Realistic" values depend a lot on the underlying (single stocks, index, commodities, etc.) For example, a broad index rarely jumps up but may very well jump down (recessions). Single stocks can jump in either directions based on good or bad firm-specific news.

Lets say for single stocks!

Maybe search for empirical papers that implement Bates? Something like this https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=9296

Will take a look! Thanks!
